# How to create Schedule Reports in Razor mvc using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I want the report to be generated at the end of the day automatically and emailed to the user. I use a SQL Server database and ASP.NET MVC with the Razor view engine.

Comment: hi! how will u find its end of the day

Comment: that is i am asking is there any methods / class /functions / procedure /triggers are available.